# Running docker with an existing volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo

Need a bit of a help to restore my Odoo instance post image update. I think it probably is gone now but wondering if I can restore it.

I did a mistake of doing the following when upgrading my Odoo instance:

1. docker pull image
2. docker stop instance
3. docker rm instance
4. docker-compose up -d

Now, I just realized that I shouldn't did this method according to their Dockerhub page - this is what should've done.

```
$ docker run --volumes-from old-odoo -p 8070:8069 --name new-odoo --link db:db -t odoo
```

Hoping to be able to re-run my instance, I've tried the following to no luck - it feels like I'm not mounting the old volume properly.

```
docker run --mount source=85e806e42968fb5ee30556ecd559420fd2f745af85aab921d64664414304317a ,target=/_data --expose 8069 --expose 80 --expose 443 --name odoo_web_1 --network nginx-proxy --link odoo_db_1:db -t odoo
```

I run into error 503 page when i try to access the site.. :(
I'm not sure if I should be using --mount or --volume to access the previously mounted volume.

I do use docker-compose and if the volume mounting is something that can be done through docker-compose, that would work best.

Or, should I just start a new instance and migrate the old database to the new one?

`docker-compose.yml` is as below

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 8069
      VIRTUAL_HOST: sub.domain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: sub.domain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: admin@domain.com
    volumes:
      - ./openerp-server.conf:/etc/openerp-server.conf
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxx

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Comment: You haven't shown what's in your `docker-compose.yml` file, but if it's configured to use a named volume, it'll keep using the same named volume when you restart it as you've shown.

Comment: upsss.. so sorry, ill edit and add the docker-compose file.
The volume is not mounted on docker-compose.
I can add external volume and I tried that, but it looks like it mounted both the volume and the new volume. =\

Comment: Did you try to run the old version with the old volume?

Comment: hi @SergioSantiago,

the docker is gone because of my step #3 so I don't think I can quickl re-run the docker there.. =\

Comment: I mean, run a new container using the old image version. To make sure your data is not corrupted.

Comment: aahh gotcha! unfortunately we were using the :latest image hence the old image is no longer there =(
I guess I can rewind back and run for every past release but wondering if there is any quicker way to solve this.. :D 
thank you @SergioSantiago

Comment: Did you used docker-compose logs -f to see in the log what is happening?

Comment: hi @DanielBlanco, yeaa.. the problem was the original docker was initially removed so there isn't much in the log file right now.. :( I ended up re-building the whole app manually.. :((

Answer (score 0):

You have not mounted your data volume (`/var/lib/odoo`) so your data files has been gone with the instance. The volumes you have mounted are for addons and config file and they are not different between your old and new image.

add this to your docker compose for the next time :) :

```
volumes:
      - ./openerp-server.conf:/etc/openerp-server.conf
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - odoo14:/var/lib/odoo
```

you can mount to a folder as well.